# Issue Pivoting Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to pivot this dataframe [photo of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLjsC.png). I am new to pandas so I don't know why I have cells like "bake" that stretch multiple rows (this was the result of a groupby).
Ideally I want "Not Math", "Could be Math", and "Math" to be column labels and the number from 'keep' in all of the cells.
Please let me know if there is any easy way to do this.

Comment: Hi, please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For `pandas`, see [How to ask a good pandas question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add reset_index, results of your groupy created a multiindex for the dataframe, to move those indexes into dataframe columns use `reset_index`, secondly in your groupby method you might try and added `as_index=False` as a parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,13,15), index = 
                  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['bake','bike','blocks','camera','clock'],['Could be Math','Math','Not Math']]))

df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   level_0        level_1   0
0     bake  Could be Math   2
1     bake           Math   7
2     bake       Not Math   5
3     bike  Could be Math  12
4     bike           Math   3
5     bike       Not Math   7
6   blocks  Could be Math   9
7   blocks           Math   4
8   blocks       Not Math   4
9   camera  Could be Math   9
10  camera           Math   7
11  camera       Not Math   9
12   clock  Could be Math   4
13   clock           Math  10
14   clock       Not Math   2
```